# bootstrap 3 increase the margin between grids

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to add space between grids, without changing `.col-md-4` and `.col-md-8` style

```
<div class="row" >
    <div class="col-md-4" style="height:250px;">grid1</div>
    <div class="col-md-8" style="height:250px;">grid2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest you add a new `div` element inside any of the `.col-md-*` and give it a padding (or a margin) (Because you can't edit the default Bootstrap files).

```
    <div class="row" >
            <div class="col-md-4" style="height:250px;">grid1</div>
            <div class="col-md-8" style="height:250px;">
                <div style="padding-left: 20px;">grid2</div> <!-- The added div -->
            </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to create a special CSS class and apply it to the rows where you want the wider spacing..

```
.row.wide-gutter [class*='col-']:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) {
  padding-right:20px;
  padding-left:20px;
}
```

Demo: http://bootply.com/110509